# Android- Sending SMS automatically

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to send sms from my app when the speed with which the car is moving exceeds 90 km/hr. For the detecting speed, i am using location.hasSpeed(). But, every time the app stops running when it reaches the Sms code.
It should send SMS when counter reaches 10.

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            curlat = location.getLatitude();
            curlong = location.getLongitude();


            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
            locationA.setLatitude(startlat);
            locationA.setLongitude(startlong);

            Location locationB = new Location("point B");
            locationB.setLatitude(curlat);
            locationB.setLongitude(curlong);

            double distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);


            if (distance > 5) {
                res = (res + distance);
                dreading.setText(String.format("%.2f", (res/1000) ));
                startlong = curlong;
                startlat = curlat;
            }
            if (location.hasSpeed()) {
                //mySpeed = location.getSpeed()*1.852;

                mySpeed = location.getSpeed() * 3.6;

                sreading.setText(String.format("%.2f", mySpeed));
                if (mySpeed > 70) {
                    warning.setText("Warning!");

                }else{
                    warning.setText("Normal");
                }
                if (mySpeed > 2) {
                    counter++;

                }


               if(counter>10)//error comes here!
                    {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alert Sent",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                String messageToSend = "Rash driving detected.\nOwner Name:"+temp+"\nDriver Name:"+temp1+"\nVehicle Number:"+temp2+ "\nLatitude:" + curlat + "\nLongitude:" + curlong + "\nCheck here:\nhttps://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + curlat + "," + curlong;
                                smsMan.sendTextMessage(temp3, null, messageToSend, null, null);
                                smsMan1.sendTextMessage(temp4, null, messageToSend, null, null);
                        counter=0;

                       }
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: There are no compilation error in the code.

Comment: where you written this listener code in Activity class or separately can you share more code or the logcat

Comment: The problem i am facing is, the sms is not sent. However, after adding permission the app is not crashing now.

Comment: private class SpeedoActionListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
whereas  i have li = new SpeedoActionListener(); in my main activity class.